# assign a variable to agents' statistics

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I have a population of agents as employees. They have a salary which has a formula to be calculated, so I defined it as dynamic variable, "salary". I want to know the average of the salaries, so I went to the statistics and defined:

```
Name: AvgSalary
Type: Average
Expression : item.Salary
```

The question is that I may need to assign this number to a variable so that it can be used in other formulas in other stages of my evaluation. How is that possible?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Your statistic object `AvgSalary` is already an object you can access. You defined it in the properties of the agent population so you can access it by baccling `myAgentPopulation.AvgSalary()` and it will always return the current value.

Hope this helps

Comment: I created a dynamic variable "AvgSalary" , and I wrote this in its property so that the values return and I can use them somewhere else: Employees.AvgSalary(), but it has an error saying that "The method AvgSalary() is undefined for the type Employees. "

Comment: Rana, what is the Employees in your model? Agent type, population of agents, ...? Java is a case-sensitive programming language. Therefore "Employees" and "employees" are considered as different names.
In order to avoid typo errors, I recommend you to type any Java code using code completion master (key sequence – Ctrl+Space).You can access the statistics collected over agent population like: <agent_population_name>.AvgSalary()